# Sending Post request by ajax to PHP page from select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've trying to set up a Question/Answer system and I've encountered with a couple of errors while setting up dependent select boxes
I wanna send the information of masters select box (Maters'id) to PHP file (DB.PHP) to handle a group of actions.

**HTML Page**

```
<?php
require_once "DB.php";
require_once "functions.php";
require_once "stuQuestion.php";
if(! isset($_SESSION['student'])){
  redirect("stulogin/login.php");
  die;
}
$date = userGets($connection , "students_questions" , $_SESSION['students_id']);
?>

<html>
  <head> 


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#masters').on('change',function() {

              var mid = $('#masters').val();
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'DB.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  data: 'mid=' + mid
              }).done(function(user){
                  console.log(user);
                  user = JSON.parse(user);
                  $('#topics').empty();
                  user.forEach(function(topic) {
                      $('#topics').append('<option>' + topic.topic + '</option>')
                  })
              })
          })
      })

  </script>

</head>




                <select class="form-control" id="masters" name="masters" >
                    <option selected disabled>Choose Master</option>
                    <?php
                    //id='".$master['id']."' value = '".$master['id']."'
                    foreach($date as $master)
                    {
                        echo "<option id='".$master['id']."' value = '".$master['id']."'> ".$master['master']."</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>



          <select class="form-control" id="topics" name="topics">

          </select>
```

**DB.php**

```
function connectToDB() {
try {

    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=university","root","");
    $connect->exec("set character set utf8");
    $connect->exec("set names utf8");
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $connect;

   } 
      catch (PDOException $e) 
   {
    die($e->getMessage());
   } }

$connection = connectToDB();

if(isset($_POST['mid'])){
$statment = $connection->prepare("SELECT  topic FROM students_questions 
WHERE user_id = " . $_POST['mid']);
$statment->execute();
$user = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($user) ;
}
else
var_dump("No Request");


function userGets($conn , $table , $user_id = null) {
$statment = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT master FROM {$table} WHERE 
user_id = :user_id");
$statment->bindParam("user_id" , $user_id );
$statment->execute();
$master = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $master ? $master : false;
}
```

When I log in and redirect to stuIndex.php (The page which contains select boxes)I will encounter with "No Request"! and after 3 days hunting around for probable correct answers, I couldn't solve it so far:(

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.
PS: if someone needs more information, please tell me I will send the complete source code or sharing more information.

Comment: Should it not be `data: { "mid": mid }`

Comment: you are not sending proper  json data  here  `data: 'mid=' + mid`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan I'd tried,didn't work:(

Comment: Errors? Console errors?

Comment: You're setting content type to JSON but sending a query string. Don't overengineer it, just do `$.post("DB.php", { mid }).done(...)` edit: sorry, didn't see all those comments when posting

Comment: @ChrisG And now they are in an answer ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah :) (at) OP: three jQuery libs...?

Comment: @mplungjan no sir, I mentioned the error was "No Request"(from DB.php)that show no post request was sent.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the data sent properly? Does it reach the backend in the expected structure?

Comment: @DanyalT See my answer. Fix the multiple libraries and come back

Comment: Also https://xkcd.com/327/  - `WHERE user_id = " . "); drop table students_questions";`

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is sending data to DB.php, unfortunately else condition will expose("No Request") if I run the application:(

Comment: So, the data doesn't even reach the backend in the expected format? What elase is sent there? Have you maybe tried what others suggested (to send the data not using a concatenated string)?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, DB.php doesn't reach post request from stuIndex.php(HTML page) It just sends a post request that contains masters' id from DB, I couldn't figure out which of those concatenations is your purpose :(

Comment: So, when you inspect the AJAX call to your backend through your browser's network console, what **exactly** does the request contain? A raw string containing the ID or a proper tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Too many jQuery and bootstrap libraries and they are  HTTPS and HTTP versions from different CDNs
2. Syntax error in data :
3. No need for parsing the JSON since it is default
4. No error handling for the request. If you do not want error handling do this

```js
$(function() {
  $('#masters').on('change', function() {
    var mid = this.value;
    if (val) {
      $.post('DB.php', {"mid": mid}, function(user) {
        $('#topics').empty();
        $.each(user,function(topic) {
          $('#topics').append('<option>' + topic.topic + '</option>')
        })
      })
    }
  })
})
```

using

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan for your answer, but it didn't work for me, I rewrite Jquery function completely, however, I encounter with same error again :(

Comment: Whatever the result, the change I suggested were necessary. You need to debug the DB.php then  - turn on error reporting and look in the network consome for response